# ReactJS: Add leading 0 before decimal

Tags: reactjs, react-number-format

I have a ReactJS field:

```
<NumberFormat
    allowNegative={false}
    InputProps={{
      endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">kg</InputAdornment>,
    }}
    label="Weight"
    customInput={TextField}
    variant="outlined"
    name="weight"
    thousandSeparator={true}
    fixedDecimalScale="0."
    decimalScale={3}
    fixedDecimalScale={true}
    value={weight}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setWeight(e.currentTarget.value);
    }}
  />;
```

What I want to do is add a leading 0 to the field when saved. So if the user enters .100 then it saves as 0.100 and if the user enters a whole number 1.100 then it doesn't change.

How do I do this? I thought about using the * 1 to get it, but then that destroys my 3 decimal places...

Comment: Have you tried regex? At first to identify ".xx" then to replace "0.xx". Or you're looking for a more smarter way?

Comment: Am open to any suggestion

Comment: Could you check whether the input `number` is smaller than `1` to conditionally add a leading `0`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add changeHandler as your onChange callback:

```
const changeHandler = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setWeight(value);
    const pattern1 = /(^.\d{3})/g;
    const pattern2 = /(^\d{1}.\d{3})/g;
    if (pattern1.test(value)) {
        setWeight(value.replace(/./, "0."));
    }if (pattern2.test(value)) {
        setIsInputValid(true);
    } else {
        setIsInputValid(false);
    }
}
```

The first `patern1` checks if you have just ".xxx" value and adds 0, and the second `patern2` checks if you have normal "x.xxx" value.

I don't know how do you implement your custom component, but to see value changes in input field you should call `setWeight(value)` on every value change and you need to validate that value. So this logic more suitable for onSubmit event, or onBlur event (to add zero when user leave the input field).